# Download additioanal functionality into an app - is it possible?

Tags: iphone

I'm currently developing an iPhone version of existing Android application.
Customer wants to provide his web services via mobile apps. On Android this is made in a modular way: user installs main app, and then he can download additional modules to it if needed. That way he can install only modules that he needs.
Is there a way to achieve same functionality on iPhone? I read about In-App Purchasing, but I don't know if it will work because additional functionality will not be built-in and unlocked - it needs to be downloaded and added to my app as a new module - so user's space would not be wasted with unneeded modules.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the question, this is not a world-facing app - it has a specific customer. With Terente's answer in mind, do consider side-loading, AKA in-house distribution. That is - bypass the app store. The prohibition on the downloadable code is an App Store policy, not a limitation of the platform.

The enterprise contract with Apple is $300/year instead of regular $100/year. But you get to install your app on as many devices as you wish, completely bypassing the App Store. Either over the air (by browsing from the phone) or via iTunes.

Under this model, your app can download, store and run custom code all you want. The specifics of the plug-in model are up for you and your customer.

EDIT: so app store is a must. How about this: have a WebView in the project, have it download HTML pages with JavaScript in them, have code hooks for JavaScript to call. To the best of my knowledge, AppStore does not reject apps that display Web pages from the Net, and if the Web page happens to have a script, there's no prohibition on executing that script.

This violates the spirit of the rule while relying on letter and precedent. Technically speaking, JavaScript IS code. And again, technically speaking, WebView is capable of downloading and running it. And App Store is choke full of apps with WebView in them.

How will this fly with your customers, who knows.

Comment: Thank you for useful information! However, this app is meant for customers, so it must be on the App Store.

Comment: @Balansse: "this app is meant for customers, so it must be on the App Store" - does not follow.

Comment: These applications would be used by end-users - they would not be used only in-house. That's why app store is a must. Thanks for some interesting ideas, will discuss them with my manager :)

Comment: @Balansse: "in-house" does not necessarily mean - within your company only. If you upload it on a public website, anyone can use it, as long as they find it.

Answer (score 5):

> 2.7   Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected

From [App Store Review Guidelines](http://stadium.weblogsinc.com/engadget/files/app-store-guidelines.pdf)